# How to apply CSS on html generated in code behind file in asp.net with C#

Tags: asp.net, html, css

i created  a html div tags that hold table in which data is coming from database via function. this html code i have written in code behind c# file. i want to apply css on div tag that written in code behind file how?

Answer (score 2):

Just make your code generate something like:

```
<div id="div" style="left: 327px; top: 9px; width: 323px; height: 138px"> </div>
```

Replace style with your custom css.

Or, if you have it declared on an external css file, then use:

```
<div id="div" class='cssClassName'/>
```

Comment: No you are not getting my point. html in dynamically created in code behind file. i want to apply css on in. the code is like this builder.Append("<div><table> ....... </table></div>"); i want to apply css class on div tag

Comment: what element is `builder` exactly?

Comment: questionOption.Append("<tr><td><input type=\"checkbox\" onclick=\"save_mcma_answer(this)\"" + " name=\"" + optionID + "\" id=\"" + optionID + "\"/></td>");
questionOption.Append("<td>" + optionText + "</td>"); this is my code in C# code behind file.  i have external css class. i want to style these type of tags or element.
                questionOption.Append("</tr>");

Comment: StringBuilder questionOption = new StringBuilder(); i append html in this. now i want to style this.how?

Comment: @Jawad, as Randolf suggested you, use the class attribute in your code behind to apply styles. It doesn't mind if its being generated. For example, use: questionOption.Append("<td CLASS='OPTION_TEXT_CSS_STYLE'>" + optionText + "</td>"); given that you have that CSS class declared on your external css.

Answer (score 1):

```
builder.Append("<div class=\"~PLACEHOLDER~\"><table> ....... </table></div>");
```

Then later in your code

```
string markup = builder.ToString().Replace("~PLACEHOLDER~", "cssClassName");
```

Comment: Why are you using a placeholder instead of just putting the classname in straight away?

Comment: It seemed like the OP wanted some way to modify the div tag after having already committed it to the string. I could be wrong on that point, and you're right -- simply adding the correct classname to the div tag is the simplest and most straightforward solution, if the classname is known at that point.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Not as crazy as I first thought. :)